# Oracle procedure giving different ASCII outputs

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus, dbms-output

This procedure prints the `ASCII` code for each character in a string.

If executed in TOAD, it prints these ASCII codes: `55 48 48 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 49` which are the right ones.

If executed via `SQLPLUS` on the `UNIX` server and spool the output of the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_String);` to a text file, copy that output and assign it to the  v_String and execute the procedure in TOAD, I get the following `ASCII` codes `55 48 48 9 32 32 49`.

Why it is replacing 32 32 32 32 32 with 9. Essentially a tab.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE My_Test
AS
   v_String   VARCHAR2 (25);
BEGIN
   v_String := RPAD ('700', 10) || '1';
   -- v_String:='700   1';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_String);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('');

   FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH (v_String)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (ASCII (SUBSTR (v_String, i, 1)));
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: Hmm, are you actually using the `spool` command to write to a file, or redirecting the terminal output to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behaviour in SQL*Plus on Unix, controlled by [its `tab` setting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG111):

> **SET TAB {ON | OFF}**
>
> Determines how SQL*Plus formats white space in terminal output. `OFF` uses spaces to format white space in the output. `ON` uses the `TAB` character. `TAB` settings are every eight characters. The default value for `TAB` is system dependent.

SQL*Plus is 'helpfully' substituting tabs as it outputs to the terminal. It's nothing to do with PL/SQL or `dbms_output` - you would see the same thing with just:

```
select '700       1' from dual;`
```

You are seeing your first three characters, then a tab instead of the five spaces to take you up to 8 characters, then the last two spaces and the final character.

In your SQL*Plus session, set do `set tab off` before you start.

You might want to set that in a script, or in a login file so it's always applied.

(Note that this only applies to terminal output, not to spool files; your question refers to spooling but I think you must actually be redirecting or capturing the output some other way.)